# after => Null Pointer

Tags: java, timestamp

I got this code, and I am trying to compare a Timestamp array:

```
Timestamp oldestTStamp = timeStamp[0];
boolean found = false; 
int temp = 0;
for (int j = 1; j<timeStamp.length; j++){  
    if(oldestTStamp == null && timeStamp[j] == null){}
    else if(oldestTStamp.after(timeStamp[j])){
        oldestTStamp = timeStamp[j];
        //Retrieve the oldest timestamp index in array
        found = true;
        temp = j; 
    }
```

This is how I assign timestamp:

```
timeStamp[index] = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Comment: `if(oldestTStamp == null && timeStamp[j] == null)` will only be true if *both* values are `null`. If `oldestTStamp` is `null`, but `timeStamp[j]` not, you'll get the mentioned `NullPointerException`. Try to use `if(oldestTStamp == null || timeStamp[j] == null)` to check if either of them is `null`.

Comment: And please adjust your title to be more meaningful - I don't understand what it's trying to convey at the moment.

Comment: No, that's *not* the right attitude. The point of Stack Overflow is to create a lasting repository of good questions to help other people. Your post does *not* do that at the moment. If your attitude is "screw other people, I've got what *I* want now" you may well find that others are less willing to help you in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` condition is written in a fairly strange way, and it only checks if both the `Timestamp`s are `null`.
You probably mean to write something like

```
if (oldestTStamp != null && timeStamp[j] != null && oldestTStamp.after(timeStamp[j])) {
    ...
```

This way the `after()` method is only called if both `oldestTStamp` and `timeStamp[j]` are non-null.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a full stacktrace of the exception, or else is just guessing.

Probably the problem is in this line:

```
 if(oldestTStamp == null && timeStamp[j] == null){}
```

It should be

```
 if(oldestTStamp == null || timeStamp[j] == null){}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with ,

```
if( oldestTStamp != null &&
    timeStamp[j] != null &&
    oldestTStamp.after(timeStamp[j])){


}
```